Bidirectional replace value in pandas
I have a dataframe(assuming large data set):



date
Security_Price
Benchmark_Price




2023-12-20
100.0
100.0


2023-12-21
105.0
95.0


2023-12-22
110.0
98.0


2023-12-23
110.0
100.0


2023-12-24
112.0
100.0


2023-12-25
112.0
100.0


2023-12-26
112.0
105.0


2023-12-27
115.0
107.0


2023-12-28
118.0
107.0


2023-12-29
120.0
107.0


2023-12-30
120.0
110.0


2023-12-31
107.0
108.0



I would like to achieve this : if on a certain date,  security price == security_price.shift(1) or benchmark_price == benchmark_price.shift(1) then both security_price and benchmark_price should use the previous valid value. Like this:



date
Security_Price
Benchmark_Price




2023-12-20
100.0
100.0


2023-12-21
105.0
95.0


2023-12-22
110.0
98.0


2023-12-23
110.0
98.0


2023-12-24
112.0
100.0


2023-12-25
112.0
100.0


2023-12-26
112.0
100.0


2023-12-27
115.0
107.0


2023-12-28
115.0
107.0


2023-12-29
115.0
107.0


2023-12-30
120.0
110.0


2023-12-31
107.0
108.0




Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Your process is inherently iterative, as seen for the row 2023-12-24, the 100 value cannot be considered identical to the previous one since that value would become 98.
Thus, you need to loop. Compare the row to the previous one, if any value is identical then replace the others by those of the previous row:
def fill(arr):
    prev = [None]*arr.shape[1]
    for i, row in enumerate(arr):
        m = row != prev
        if not m.all():
            row[m] = prev[m]
            arr[i] = row
        prev = row
    return arr

# columns to consider
cols = ['Security_Price', 'Benchmark_Price']

df[cols] = fill(df[cols].to_numpy())

NB. this should work with any number of columns.
Output:
          date  Security_Price  Benchmark_Price
0   2023-12-20           100.0            100.0
1   2023-12-21           105.0             95.0
2   2023-12-22           110.0             98.0
3   2023-12-23           110.0             98.0
4   2023-12-24           112.0            100.0
5   2023-12-25           112.0            100.0
6   2023-12-26           112.0            100.0
7   2023-12-27           115.0            107.0
8   2023-12-28           115.0            107.0
9   2023-12-29           115.0            107.0
10  2023-12-30           120.0            110.0
11  2023-12-31           107.0            108.0

